# How to rotate and scale the image from -45 to 45 degree?

Tags: xamarin.android, rotation, scale, android-bitmap

I want to rotate(-45 to 45 degrees like tilt feature) and scale the image based on the degree.

I tried to set the scale value by using this calculation (angle * Math.PI) / 180.0. But it is not scaling the image based on the image size. If I set the horizontal image means there is a space in left and right side of the image.

Can you please provide any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to rotate the image using following code. compasImageView is image which i was rotating 360 degree

```
 private void Rotateimage(double angle)
 {
  ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.OfFloat(compasImageView, "rotation", 130, 0f);
  objectAnimator.SetDuration(500);
  objectAnimator.Start();
  compasImageView.Animate().RotationBy((float)angle).SetDuration(1500).SetInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()).Start();
 }
```

Can you please share your code. If suggested code is not helping.